Multiple Access to two-dimensional array (using setters/getter via Proxy or Object.defineProperty)
I have a two dimensional array that I need to perform read and write action on from various angles.
Sometimes I need to get/set a single row (easy of course) and sometimes I need to get/set a single column or even just a single cell but coming from a column perspective.
Let me try to explain what I want to achieve:
function myFunction() {

  var myArray = [['a1','b1'],['a1','b1']];

  var ds = new DataStructure(myArray);
  console.log(ds) // -> [['a1','b1'],['a1','b1']]

  console.log(da[0]) // -> ['a1','b1']
  console.log(da[1]) // -> ['a2','b2']

  console.log(da.cols[0]) // -> ['a1','a2']
  console.log(da.cols[1]) // -> ['b1','b2']
  da.cols[0] = ['A1','A2']
  console.log(da.cols[0]) // -> ['A1','A2']
  da.cols[1][1] = 'Q2'
  console.log(da.cols[1]) // -> ['b1','Q2']

  console.log(ds) // -> [['A1','b1'],['A1','Q1']]

  console.log(myArray) // -> [['A1','b1'],['A1','Q1']]
}

So basically I want to have a wrapper to my original data structure and all get/set access to it should work directly on the original structure (by reference I reckon).
Any idea?
I have tried to use Proxy() and Object.defineProperty() to define custom getters/setters.
It kind of works but as soon as I access into a column i.e. ds.cols[0][0] it doesn't work anymore.

How do you get 'a2' and 'b2'? The data does not have such strings in it. Also, da is not even declared.

I have tried - show what you tried - perhaps it's an easy fix

Do you have to treat cols as a property? Why not use methods, da.rows(1) and da.cols(1)? Then you don't need any fancy coding like getters or proxies.

You need create custom class which will encapsulate and expose setter and getters set/get values specified rows and columns.
In the below example refer the how values being set/get in myFunction method.
Refer the below example:


class DataStructure {
  constructor(array) {
    this.array = array;
    this.cols = new Proxy({}, this.getColumnHandler());
  }

  getColumnHandler() {
    return {
      get: (target, prop) => {
        if (typeof prop === 'symbol') return target[prop];
        const colIndex = Number(prop);
        if (isNaN(colIndex)) return undefined;
        return this.array.map(row => row[colIndex]);
      },
      set: (target, prop, value) => {
        const colIndex = Number(prop);
        if (isNaN(colIndex)) return false;
        value.forEach((val, rowIndex) => {
          if (this.array[rowIndex]) {
            this.array[rowIndex][colIndex] = val;
          }
        });
        return true;
      }
    };
  }

  getRow(rowIndex) { // Get row by index
    return this.array[rowIndex];
  }

  setRow(rowIndex, row) {
    this.array[rowIndex] = row;
  }

  getCell(rowIndex, colIndex) { // Get cell by row index and column index
    return this.array[rowIndex][colIndex];
  }

  setCell(rowIndex, colIndex, value) { Set cell by row index and column index
    this.array[rowIndex][colIndex] = value;
  }
}


function myFunction() {
  var myArray = [['a1', 'b1'], ['a2', 'b2']];
  var ds = new DataStructure(myArray);
  ds.cols[0] = ['A4', 'A2']; // Set column by index 
  ds.setRow(0,['A9', 'A0']) // Set row by index 
  ds.setCell(1,1,'Q2'); // Set cell by column and row 
  return ds;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(myFunction));




Thank you! That solves my problem just perfectly!
